# Adding to an object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I have created the following arraylist:

```
premierLeague = new ArrayList<FootballClub>();
```

I have the following code which creates a FootballClub object and places it into the arraylist:

```
System.out.println("Name of club:");
String name = input.next();
System.out.println("Location of club:");
String location = input.next();
FootballClub newClub = new FootballClub(name, location); // If only the name and location are placed in the new object, does that mean that all other stats are set to 0?
premierLeague.add(newClub);
System.out.println("Football club added! size = " + premierLeague.size());
```

I also have the following code to iterate through the arraylist to check if the FootballClub name the user enters matches an object of FootballClub in the arraylist.

```
Iterator<FootballClub> it = premierLeague.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if (it.next().getClubName().equals(homeName)) {

    }
}
```

The Football class has other methods (aside from `name` and `location`), such as `gamesWon`, `gamesLost` and `Points`. How do allow the user to enter a name and score of a footballclub which is then added to the existing object? For example, if the user enters 'Arsenal' as a club, and a score of 2, the program should find the object with the name = "Arsenal" and then add a score of 2 to the `Points`method inside the object.

The FootballClub class has getters and setters for all variables.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Are you facing an error?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: it sounds like a report than a quesion...

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through your collection until you meet a club whose name is equal to what the user entered, and then with the club that you match, call .addScore(2) or something.

Comment: There is no question mark, but he does ask a question. I think the question mark is just omitted, perhaps by typing error:

"How do allow the user to enter a name and score of a footballclub which is then added to the existing object."